# How could breakpoints cannot be bound in VSCode using debugger for chrome?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a nodejs project and I want to debug it using chrome debugger plugin in vscode. even though I tried many times after searched and learned from the Internet, I still failed.

below is my config file:

[image: launch.json]

and this is the project structure :

[image: project structure]

the result is:

[image: not bound]

and the output of `.scripts` likes this :

[image: scripts command]

how can I modify my config to debug normally? thanks in advance.

---

moreover, if I set breakpoints in chrome's devTools and matched (of course chrome cannot miss its breakpoints), vscode stops code execution, too. at present, I can execute step by step (including F10, F11, etc) using vscode's button.